# actionscript 3 - Error #2136

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So im trying to understand how I can call a function from one class from another class. Im getting a few errors and am wondering if someone can explain what im doing wrong here.

Main file:

```
package code {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import code.*;
    import code.functions.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var _playerHP:Number;
    public var _enemyYellow:EnemyYellow;

    public function Main() {

        _enemyYellow = new EnemyYellow;

        _playerHP = 10;
        _playerHPdisplay.text = _playerHP.toString();
        trace("loaded")

    }

    public function lowerHP ():void
    {   
        _playerHP -= 1;
        _playerHPdisplay.text = _playerHP.toString();
        trace(_playerHP)

    }
  }
}
```

Second File:

```
package code.functions {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    import code.Main;

 public class EnemyYellow extends MovieClip {

    public var _main:Main;


    public function EnemyYellow() {

        _main = new Main;

        _main.lowerHP();
         trace ("test")
   }
  }
}
```

It will then load with a blackscreen and the following error:

```
Error: Error #2136: The SWF file file:///test/Main.swf contains invalid data.
at code.functions::EnemyYellow()[test\code\functions\EnemyYellow.as:15]
at code::Main()[test\code\Main.as:16]
Error opening URL 'file:///test/Main.swf'
```

However, If I remove _enemyYellow = new EnemyYellow; from the Main file it loads but the second file is not loaded.

If I remove _main = new Main; from the Second file, the game again loads but it does not call the lower HP function, and I get the following error

```
 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at code.functions::EnemyYellow()[test\code\functions\EnemyYellow.as:16]
at code::Main()[test\code\Main.as:16]
```

If anyone could help me it would be appreciated. Im just trying to get my head around how to call a function from another file..

_playerHPdisplay.text is also a text box on the stage when the game loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not assign a value to _main, it is null. That's why you receive the #1009 if you do not assign new Main() to it.

However, you do not want to create a new Main object either.
The main class represents the application and generally speaking you do no explicitly instantiate it in your project.

To make your code work, you have to pass a reference of Main to the enemy class.

A better approach to this is to let the enemy class dispatch events, so that the Main class can be notified "some damage was dealt". This however will not work from within the constructor of enemy.

Think about whether your package names make sense. Pretty much all packages contain code, which makes "code" a not very informative name. The package "functions" contains the *class* EnemyYellow, which doesn't seem to be a good fit.